# How to create a tflite file from saved_model (SSD MobileNet)

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I want to create an object-detection app based on a retrained ssd_mobilenet model I've retrained like the guy on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COlbP62-B-U&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcNK5GeCQnxYnSSaar2tpku).

I chose the model `ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco` from the [Tensorflow Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md). After the retraining process I've got the model with the following structure:

```
- saved_model
    - variables (empty folder)
    - saved_model.pb
- checkpoint
- frozen_inverence_graph.pb
- model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
- model.ckpt.index
- model.ckpt.meta
- pipeline.config
```

In the same folder, I have the python script with the following code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("saved_model")
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

After running this code, I got the following error:

```
ValueError: None is only supported in the 1st dimension. Tensor 'image_tensor' has invalid shape '[None, None, None, 3]'.
```

It seems, that the image width and hight is missing in the model. When I use the model like in the youtube video, it is working.

After lots of research and attempts I tried other ways, like running bazel/toco, but nothing helped me to create a tflite-file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it describes in [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api#exporting_a_savedmodel_), you can pass different parameters in `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model`.

> For more complex SavedModels, the optional parameters that can be passed into `TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model()` are `input_arrays, input_shapes, output_arrays, tag_set and signature_key`. Details of each parameter are available by running `help(tf.lite.TFLiteConverter)`.

You can pass this information as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter#from_saved_model). You need to provide input tensor name and its shape, and also output tensor name and its shape. And for `ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco`, you need to define on which input shape you need to use the network like this:

```
tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("saved_model", input_shapes={"image_tensor" : [1,300,300,3]})
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped to solve this problem. I have removed the unnecessary brackets between the curly brackets.Now I get an other problem, that i got with bazel/toco: Check failed: dim_size >= 1 (0 vs. 1)

Comment: How do I decide the input shape? Trained from a mobilenet_coco, I can just throw images with different sizes at the tensorflow model and it works. Do I have to convert it for each input resolution I want to use it via tflite?